# Autowiring a list in spring, without configuration

Tags: spring, autowired

How can I autowire a list using java, without configuration?

Say I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract doStuff();
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("I'm B");
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("I'm C");
    }
}
```

And I have the class

```
public class Aggregator {
    @Autowired
    private List<A> stuffDoers;
    private void doAllStuff() {
        for(A a:stuffDoers) {
            a.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I *autowire* some of A's implementation into the `Aggregator` without configuring a list in XML?

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to be able to control the members  of a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired` always works with instances of a class, not types. You have defined 3 types: `A`, `B` and `C`, but have not created any instances from them.

To autowire, you need to create these instances, and also register them with Spring. This is where the XML config or Java config comes in. It is basically a short form for creating Spring-registered instances. So you can specify:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public B someA() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Bean
    public C anotherA() {
        return new C();
    }

    @Bean
    public B evenMoreA() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

This gives you 3 independent instance beans (not a list). For more details, see [Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java).

Now, Spring will do the job of finding all beans of type `A` in those packages, and populate your `Aggregator` class with all three beans correctly.

**NOTE:** These beans don't need to be in the same file. They can be declared anywhere in your `@ComponentScan` packages.

---

As asked in a comment, *what if you want to have only some of those instances?*

If you want only **some of the beans** added to your list, the situation is more tricky. You will need to move the excluded beans to a separate `@Configuration` class, in a **different package**. You should not add that new package to the Spring `@ComponentScan` packages, so Spring will not find those beans to add to the list. As far as I know, this is the only way.

Of course, if you want only **a single bean**, then as usual, you have to autowire it using `@Qualifier` and specify the bean name. In this case, you don't use a `List`, just the variable of type `A`.

Comment: I asked how to do this without configuration, just in java.

Comment: @user1050389 ah fair enough, will add a JavaConfig example.

Comment: You mentioned it gives three independent beans and not a list. Would this work these independent beans be autowired as a list? Otherwise it doesn't answer the question..OK I see you referenced that as well. Thanks!

Comment: But what if I want to have only some of those instances?

Comment: @user1050389 Answered your additional question as an edit. Check the answer.